Can't Retrieve Deleted Items by Other Users from SharePoint Recycle Bin via REST API, but Can See Them on Website
I have a Site Collection Administrator account on a SharePoint (On-Prem SharePoint Server Subscription Edition) site, and I need to programmatically retrieve deleted items from the Recycle Bin using the SharePoint REST API.
When I use the following API call, I can only retrieve the items I deleted:
GET https://{site_url}/_api/web/RecycleBin

However, when I view the Recycle Bin through the SharePoint website, I can see items deleted by other users, as well restore them.
What I have tried:

Site Collection Admin Permissions: I have confirmed that I am a Site Collection Administrator, and I can see items deleted by others through the SharePoint UI.
API Call: The API call returns only the items deleted by me, even though I can see all deleted items on the website.

What I am trying to achieve:
I need to retrieve all deleted items (including those deleted by other users) via the SharePoint REST API, similar to what I can see on the website.
My questions:

Is there a specific permission or setting required to access deleted items by other users through the REST API?
Is there an alternative method (perhaps through Microsoft Graph API or some other approach) to retrieve these items?

Any help or guidance on this issue would be appreciated!
